# Date of first day of calendarweek

Tags: python, date

I'd like to get the date of the beginning of the week, given a calendar week:

```
>>> calendarweek_to_date(2017, 52, 1)
datetime.date(2017, 12, 25)
```

Currently I'm finding the weekday by using `isocalendar()[2]` then create a weekday and then subtract a timedelta with the appropriate days.

```
weekday = date_object.isocalendar()[2]  # Monday := 1 .. Sunday := 7
weekday -= 1  # Monday := 0 .. Sunday := 6
offset = timedelta(days=weekday)
last_monday = date_object - offset
```

However I'm appalled by my current solution and believe there **must be a better way**.

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you. This question will serve to redirect.